# ConcurrentHashMap with ArrayList as value

Tags: java, concurrency, arraylist, hashmap

I need to use a HashMap of the form `<String, ArrayList<String>>` that is going to be 
accessed by several different threads. From what I've managed to understand, ConcurrentHashMap is the preferred method. But will there be any problem with the fact that the value of the map is an ArrayList? Do I have to define the value as a synchronized ArrayList or something like that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

yes, there can be a problem.  The ConcurrentHashMap will be thread safe for accesses into the Map, but the Lists served out need to be thread-safe, *if* multiple threads can operate on the same List instances concurrently.

So use a thread-safe list if that is true.

Edit -- now that i think about it, the rabbit-hole goes further.  You have your Map, you have your List, and you have the objects in the list.  Anything multiple threads can modify should be thread safe.  So if many threads can modify the Map, Lists, and Objects in the Lists, then all of those should have thread-safety guards.  If only the Map and List instances can be modified concurrently, only they need thread safety.  If multiple threads can read everything, but not modify, then you don't need any thread safety (I think, someone will correct me if this is wrong)

Comment: I see...so how do I use a thread safe list? I mean, how do I initialize the ConcurrentHashMap? I can't write new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Collections.synchronizedList<String>>()...

Comment: Well assuming that access to the same List will be extremely rare, just synchronizing on the list AFTER you get it from the HashMap (synchronize(list) {}) should work just fine. Otherwise Collections.synchronizedList() still returns a normal list, so you don't have to change the signature of the hashmap - just make sure only to add synchronized lists to the map.

Comment: @Moshe: To make Voo's comment more clear: use `<String, List<String>>` as the type parameter of your map, not `<String, someSpecialListType<String>>`. Then you can put in any list you want - you don't need to know which implementation, normally.

Answer (score 0):

ConcurrentHashMap guarantees atomicity in its mutating methods e.g. putIfAbsent, computeIfAbsent, computeIfPresent so if all the modification is done through these methods no problems will arise.

But at the same time, multiple threads can read the same map entry (concurrent reads are allowed). therefore multiple threads can access and modify an unsafe collection (map value)